# Revision control on a machine without root privileges

Tags: linux, version-control

I am using a computational server (Scientific Linux) that I don't have root privileges on. I want to keep track of changes I make to my code and any forking I do.

Subversion looks like a natural fit for this but I don't think I can set it up without root privileges. Does anyone know any simple revision control scripts I can use?

## Edit:

Judging by the answer, I conclude that I wasn't clear about something. I don't want to upload my code to any other server. I simply want to copy it locally to a dedicated folder (or something similar). We do an hourly backup of the data on that machine.

Comment: *None* of the answers say that uploading to any other server is required. All four suggestions use fully self-contained repositories, everything in a single directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also Subversion can easily be used locally without root privileges. First create a local repository with

```
svnadmin create <repo_dir>
```

and then do a checkout with

```
svn checkout file:///<path_to_repo_dir> <checkout_dir>
```

Works like a charm without requireing any special privileges. You could even access the repository over svn+ssh if you have SSH access to that machine via

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://user@host/<path_to_repo_dir> <checkout_dir>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most popular [distributed version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) systems can work without root privileges. The repository is entirely self-contained.

For example, the only command needed to convert the current directory into a **Git** or **Hg** (aka Mercurial) repository is **`git init`** and **`hg init`** respectively. All data stays within the same directory, although it's very easy to push to another server over SSH.

---

If the program is not installed yet, doing it yourself is possible – just download the source code, compile, and install somewhere in your home directory (for example, `~/usr` or `~/.local`). This works very well with Git; I have not tested yet with Hg.

Prepare (adjust `$HOME/usr` if wanted):

```
local="$HOME/usr"
export PATH="$local/bin:$PATH"
```

Install Git:

```
mkdir -p "$local"
wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.8.tar.gz -O - | tar xz
cd git-1.7.8
./configure --prefix "$local" && make && make install
```

To use, set PATH again as in the "Prepare" step.

Answer (score 0):

Another DVCS worth to be considered (of course it will work as simple user) is [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

It has a ton of tempting features:

- single small-sized binary with no external dependencies
- works on all mainstream operating systems
- built-in web interface, tickets, wiki, blog (it's known as "github in a box")
- its "dad" is D. Richard Hipp - the author of sqlite